# iOS: TestFlight beta app get new advertising identifier in each run

Tags: ios, uniqueidentifier, ads, testflight

I am getting new advertising identifier each time I run a beta app uploaded to TestFlight in iTunesConnect. 
Is it a normal behaviour? 
Will it happen for AppStore app too? 
I am using the Advertising Identifier to identify users and his credentials in some context. But if it changes in every run, the user have to activate in each run.

```
[[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
```

In testflight build, in 3 runs, I got, e.g.

```
ID: 3E841B61-B007-44D3-B654-6C857122301E
ID: 2EC3682A-D162-4CE6-B07A-8B73282456A4
ID: 1D8513EA-0757-4E5F-8CEE-B6C4F782E966
```

This does not happen in debug or ad hoc builds. 
Can anybody shed some light on it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is by design. It started happening in 2014. It will only happen in a TestFlight app, not in a production app in the app store. It's unfortunate--it makes it hard to test some apps realistically with actual beta testers.

In the WWDC 2014 talk, ["User Privacy in iOS and OS X," by David Stites and Katie Skinner](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#715), they mention this. (This link only works in Safari.) You can see it in [slide #8 of their slide deck](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/715xx4loqo5can9/715/715_user_privacy_in_ios_and_os_x.pdf?dl=1).

In [this transcript of the talk](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/715), you'll find: "Also this year, for TestFlight apps the advertising identifier will be different each time you call the API."

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That used to scares me a lot.