# iOS, DfP and Google Mobile SDK: Frequency Capping fails

Tags: ios, interstitial, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

I am running into a problem in our iOS app. I have set up interstitials in both DoubleClick for Publishers Small Business. The implementation in our app was straight-forward and interstitials get displayed when my triggers are being hit.

Now I want to limit the interstitials with a frequency cap of once per day. I have set this up in the corresponding line item, but this does not seem to be respected inside the app.

Example: I have set up a frequency cap of once per day. I open the app, get to the point where the interstitial ad shows, I click away the interstitial and close the app. When I open the app again and navigate to the interstitial target point, I get another interstitial - although as far as I understand this the frequency cap should be working in this case.

As a sidenote, in the Android app with a different line item, but otherwise similar setup, everything works fine.

Do I have to set something special inside the iOS Ad request code? Or is there a special DfP setting for iOS apps to allow frequency capping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here: the problem was that this behavior occured when using a Testflight build. Frequency capping works by storing the Advertising Identifier in the adserver and thus identifying users.

With [Testflight builds, the Advertising Identifier changes every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648840/ios-testflight-beta-app-get-new-advertising-identifier-in-each-run). Therefore the ad server cannot track the user and sends out a new interstitial every time.