# advertisingIdentifier changes every time on iOS 9.3 simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9.3

Does anyone notice that method `-[ASIdentifierManager advertisingIdentifier]` changes every time when app launchs ? while on iOS simulator <= 9.3 and iOS Real Device 9.3 , it keep un-changed when app launch.(that's the expected behavior)
What happened?

Comment: Just noticed that I have the same problem, have you found out what the problem was?

Comment: Apparently this seems to answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648840/ios-testflight-beta-app-get-new-advertising-identifier-in-each-run